# Working in jsfiddle.net but not in my page

Tags: jquery

I tried running this in jsfiddle.net and its working fine. http://jsfiddle.net/AdTK3/

HTML

```
<input name="rdoNationality" class="rdoNationality" type="radio" checked="checked" value="nationalityAny" /> Div 1
<input name="rdoNationality" class="rdoNationality" type="radio" value="nationalitySelect" /> Div 2 

<div id="nationalityAny">
 Div 1 Selected
</div>
<div id="nationalitySelect" style="display:none;">
  Div 2 Selected
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(function(){
    $(".rdoNationality").on("click", function(){
            var valNationality = $(this).val(),
            divNationality = $("#" + valNationality);

            $("div").hide();
                divNationality.show();
        });
});
```

But when I tried it on my page its not working (Note : Im sure my path to jQuery is correct). Here is my full HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Title Here</title>
<meta name="keywords" content="kw here" />
<meta name="content-language" content="en" />
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
    $(".rdoNationality").on("click", function(){
            var valNationality = $(this).val(),
            divNationality = $("#" + valNationality);

            $("div").hide();
                divNationality.show();
        });
});

</script>
</head>
<body style="background:#fff;">
<div>
        <input name="rdoNationality" class="rdoNationality" type="radio" checked="checked" value="nationalityAny" /> Div 1
        <input name="rdoNationality" class="rdoNationality" type="radio" value="nationalitySelect" /> Div 2 

        <div id="nationalityAny">
            Div 1 Selected
        </div>
        <div id="nationalitySelect" style="display:none;">
           Div 2 Selected
        </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Whats wrong with my code. Thanks.

Comment: what version of jQuery are you referring in your local page?

Comment: check your console for errors. Also `change` is the best event for radio

Comment: make sure the oath to your jquery.js file is correct..

Comment: CHECK YOR CONSOLE MAY BE U HAVE PLACED JQUERY FILE WRONG

Comment: *"Im sure my path to jQuery is correct"* How sure are you? How did you verify that it is loaded? [Learn how to **debug** JavaScript](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners)

Comment: Also, please link your fiddle.

Comment: Provide the fiddle link here. and make sure of version of jquery included in your page. Also include some error if you are able to see.

Comment: Im sure my jQuery is correct because if I view the source and copy the path, I can view the jQuery source

Comment: instead use this `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: @user1671639 $("div") will select all the div in the document , your checkbox is wrapped in a div,so it will hidden

Comment: @SarathSprakash Maybe you must be referring the wrong person.  check the fiddle in my answer.

Comment: @PaulSanchez $("div") will select all the div in the document , your checkbox is wrapped in a div,so it will hidden – SarathSprakash 1 min ago edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better add the online jQuery CDN version like

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
         src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Also change is the better event for radio and checkboxes.  So try like this

```
$(function(){
    $(".rdoNationality").on("change", function(){
            var valNationality = $(this).val(),
            divNationality = $("#" + valNationality);

            $("div").hide();
                divNationality.show();
        });
});
```

Check this raw [**JSfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/8GNEp/4/)

Comment: @user1671639 this is a wrong answer, how about the person has another div in the page check your update fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/8GNEp/6/. I have added an extra div ,now see that div is also hiding

Comment: @SarathSprakash Why are you caring more than given?  OP has written the code that contains only 2 divs and **if you check the question, working in fiddle and but not in local**.  The reason wrong reference in jQuery.  Thoughts welcomed.

Comment: @user1671639,I appreciate your work , but I dont think your method is correct

Comment: @SarathSprakash Mehod??  I haven't used any methods here.  Just pointed the right reference path and asked OP to use `change` event instead of `click` which is pretty better for radio and checkboxes.  Anyway thanks.

Comment: @user1671639 well thats ok. I just wanted to show the code of yours might become an error later.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because of the selector `$("div").hide();` , 
this will hide all the div in the document.

Comment: THis will hide all the `div` right.  Can you please check the second line `divNationality.show();`.  Totally his HTML has only 2 divs.  This is not the reason.  Question titled "Working in jsfiddle.net but not in my page"

Comment: @user1671639 His html has only two div now,but later if he add other elements to the page It will again be a problem,am I right or not?, Am not arguing ,Just showing what I found wrong

Comment: Good point.  But my question is why making him to divert from actually question? and I don't know he is going to add new div ;) You can even check the OP's fiddle in the comments.

Answer (score -1):

You are missing document.ready function...the meaning is after all dom elements has been loade in page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".rdoNationality").on("change", function(){
            var valNationality = $(this).val(),
            divNationality = $("#" + valNationality);

            $("div").hide();
                divNationality.show();
        });
 });
</script>
```

Comment: `$(function(){..` is equivalent to `$(document).ready(function(){`.  So that is not a problem here.